# When will be the "from" address of transaction will be a contract address?

Tags: solidity

In ethereum, a transaction can always be triggered from EOA (Wallet Account).
But in block explorer, I see transactions which are grouped as internal with "from" address as a contract address.

https://etherscan.io/txsInternal?block=14441070

I tried a test contract on local blockchain using all the different ways to interact with other deployed contracts and all of them has EOA account as the from account.

```
const AToken = await ethers.getContractFactory('A');
  const atoken = await AToken.deploy();

  await atoken.deployed();
  let aTokenAddress = atoken.address;

  const BToken = await ethers.getContractFactory('B');
  const btoken = await BToken.deploy();

  await btoken.deployed();
  let bTokenAddress = btoken.address;


  const bContractInstance = await ethers.getContractAt('B', bTokenAddress);
  console.log(await bContractInstance.incrementOtherWithAbi(aTokenAddress));
  console.log(await bContractInstance.incrementOtherWithCall(aTokenAddress));
  console.log(await bContractInstance.incrementOtherWithDelegateCall(aTokenAddress));
  console.log(await bContractInstance.getAddress());
```

Contract Code

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
contract A {

  uint256 count;

  event Increment(address indexed _calle, uint256 count);

  function name() pure external returns(string memory){
    return "contractA";
  }

  function increment() external returns(address) {
    count++;
    emit Increment(msg.sender, count);
    return msg.sender;
  }

  function getAddress() external view returns(address) {
    return address(this);
  }
}



// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
import './contractA.sol';
contract B {

  uint256 count;

  function name() pure external returns(string memory){
    return "contractB";
  }

  function incrementOtherWithAbi(address _addr) external returns(address) {
     A callee = A(_addr);
     return callee.increment();
  }

  function incrementOtherWithDelegateCall(address _addr) external returns(address) {
      (bool success, bytes memory result) = _addr.delegatecall(abi.encodeWithSignature("increment()"));
      require(success,"delegate call failed");
      return abi.decode(result,(address));
  }


  function incrementOtherWithCall(address _addr) external returns(address) {
    (bool success, bytes memory result) = _addr.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("increment()"));
    require(success,"call failed");
    return abi.decode(result,(address));
  }


  function getAddress() external view returns(address) {
    return address(this);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

incrementOtherWithAbi and incrementOtherWithCall will have msg.sender as your Contract B address

incrementOtherWithDelegateCall will have msg.sender as the EOA that initiate the transaction

you can try the following code with some slight changes on Remix, i added lastSender to record the sender

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
contract A {

  uint256 count;

  address public lastSender; 

  event Increment(address indexed _calle, uint256 count);

  function name() pure external returns(string memory){
    return "contractA";
  }

  function increment() external returns(address) {
    count++;
    emit Increment(msg.sender, count);
    lastSender = msg.sender;
    return msg.sender;
  }

  function getAddress() external view returns(address) {
    return address(this);
  }
}


contract B {

  uint256 count;

  address public lastSender;
  
  function name() pure external returns(string memory){
    return "contractB";
  }

  function incrementOtherWithAbi(address _addr) external returns(address) {
     A callee = A(_addr);
     return callee.increment();
  }

  function incrementOtherWithDelegateCall(address _addr) external returns(address) {
      (bool success, bytes memory result) = _addr.delegatecall(abi.encodeWithSignature("increment()"));
      require(success,"delegate call failed");
      return abi.decode(result,(address));
  }


  function incrementOtherWithCall(address _addr) external returns(address) {
    (bool success, bytes memory result) = _addr.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("increment()"));
    require(success,"call failed");
    return abi.decode(result,(address));
  }


  function getAddress() external view returns(address) {
    return address(this);
  }
}
```